# What's the button on Windows Speech Recognition do?

Tags: windows-7, speech-recognition

I really like the speech recognition that comes with Windows 7, but I'm left wondering what this button does:

[image: aforementioned button]

It seems to do nothing, and the hover text doesn't really help me much. What does it do?

Comment: I think it means it is listening. What happens when you click it?

Comment: @ekaj: It seems to do nothing as far as I can tell. But it does seem to stop listening if I click it when it is.

Comment: @Ullallulloo The button is intended to switch between "Listening" and "Sleeping". However, you'll notice that at times (more often than not), this button, seems to not respond. It's actually a problem that Windows Speech Recognition app has had for years. It just doesn't respond in a timely manner sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It starts the listening mode. From http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Use-Speech-Recognition-to-operate-windows-and-programs

> To open Speech Recognition
>
> Open Speech Recognition by clicking the Start button , clicking All Programs, clicking Accessories, clicking Ease of Access, and then clicking Windows Speech Recognition.
>
> Say "start listening" or click the **Microphone button** to start the listening mode.